# jquery hover not reverting back on 'mouseleave'

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which loads the background image when hovering on some text, but when leaving the text the background image stays, rather than reverting to the background colour. I cant see any reason why this is not triggering.

```
jQuery('#rollover1').on('mouseenter', function(){
   jQuery('#container').css('background-image', 'url(IMAGE URL)');
});
jQuery('#rollover1').on('mouseleave', function(){
  jQuery('#container').css('background-color', '#222222');
});
```

Comment: You need to remove the background image on `mouseleave` like this : `jQuery('#container').css('background-image', 'none');`

Comment: On `mouseenter` `background-image` css property is set, but it's not removed on `mouseleave`. You might wanna remove it!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on({
   
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(this).css({
            "background-image":"url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/24/09/28/great-2339957_1280.jpg')",
            "background-size":"cover",
            "background-position":"center"
            });
        },  
       
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).css({
            "background-image": "",
            "background-color": "red"
            });
        }
       
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:red;">this is my code.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify the `background-image` value to override it, `background-color` is completely a different CSS attribute, here is a working snippet:

```js
jQuery('#rollover1').on('mouseenter', function(){
   jQuery('#container').css('background-image', 'url(https://via.placeholder.com/450?text=Visit+Blogging.com+Non)');
});

jQuery('#rollover1').on('mouseleave', function(){
  jQuery('#container').css({backgroundColor:'red', backgroundImage:'none'});
});
```

```css
#rollover1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="rollover1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have suggested, on mouseleave, remove the image by setting it to none and set a background color.

You can try the snippet below.

```js
$('#rollover1').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $('#container').css('background-image', 'url(https://picsum.photos/200/300)');
});
$('#rollover1').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('#container').css('background-image', 'none');
  $('#container').css('background-color', '#222222');
});
```

```css
#container {
height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="rollover1">
<div id="container">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated anywhere that you want to remove the image. So if you want to remove the image you need to state it explicitly.

```
jQuery('#rollover1').on('mouseenter', () => {
jQuery('#container').css('background-image', 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/157px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png")');
}).on('mouseleave', () => {
jQuery('#container').css('background-image','none').css('background-color', '#222222');
});
```